# Web basedmMusic player for Client side files

Tags: html, web, audio-player

I wish to create a web based music player for fun. 
I wish to access local file system . The client user should be able to select a directory and play songs in it.

I understand its not a good design and usually client side languages dont get access to local file system. But with advent of web Os and other stuff, there should be some technology which enables this with users consent .

I considered using vaadin for now , but wont mind changing my development env if required.

Comment: ["HP webOS is a mobile operating system based on a Linux kernel, initially developed by Palm, which was later acquired by Hewlett-Packard. The official name is webOS, uncapitalised, but WebOS is also used.
WebOS was introduced by Palm in January 2009. Various versions of webOS have been featured on several devices, including Pre, Pixi, and Veer phones and the HP TouchPad tablet."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebOS) Try again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014176/jquery-how-to-create-audio-elements-from-local-files-using-file-api-filereader
This comes close , but I cant give the file path programatically .. the user needs to select everytime

Comment: am still looking for it , there is such a huge difference in support for html5 and local file accessing limitations, desktop app sounds easier